# Why can't I apply a criteria on a sub-query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
select Store.Id, (select COUNT(*) from StoreProduct
where StoreProduct.Store_id = Store.Id) as _count from Store where _count > 3
```

SQL Server says it's invalid because the column name '_count' is invalid. Why it's invalid if I'm declaring it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select Id as StoreId, count(*) as ProductCount
from StoreProduct
group by Id
having count(*) > 3
```

---

Another way

```
select S.Id, count(SP.ProductId) as ProductCount
from Store S
left join StoreProduct SP on (SP.Store_id = S.Id)
group by S.Id
having COUNT(SP.ProductId) > 3
```

Which, assumes, the unique column in your StoreProduct table is named ProductId

Comment: +1 Indeed it works.. but I'm still curious: Why my __count column isn't recognized even in the having clause? Or better.. why do you have to put the count(*) in the having instead of it's alias, ProductCount? I tried and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

It's invalid to the WHERE clause because of the order of evaluation in SQL. The WHERE clause is second in the list, so can only see items present in the FROM clause (which is evaluated first).
[This old article](http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/sql/node22.html) has a breakdown of the evaluation order. I'm sure there's a newer one out there.

Comment: The link you provided is broken. FYI.

Answer (score 1):

'as' is used to logically rename a field within a query.  You can't use it to rename a table, which is what your subquery returns, even though we know by context that the table returned by the subquery will only contain a single row.

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Yes it helps. Actually I was wondering why I can't use the alias even in the 'having' clause. Your explanation seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a name that begins with a letter instead of an underscore.

Comment: Invalid column name 'acount'.

Comment: underscores are perfectly valid according to standard identifier rules.

Comment: Interesting. Good to know... guess that is consistent with how you can start identifiers with underscore in VB too. I did not know this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this?

```
select Store_id as Id, COUNT(1) as acount
from StoreProduct
group by Store_id
having count(1) > 3
```

Comment: select Store.Id, (select COUNT(*) from StoreProduct where StoreProduct.Store_id = Store.Id) as acount from Store having acount > 3

also didn't work.. it says acount is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this:

```
select a.StoreId,count(*) as TotProducts
from Store a
join StoreProduct b on b.storeId=a.storeID
group by a.storeID
having count(*) > 3
```

It appears that is what you are trying to accomplish?