# Error with where clause in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have following sql query when i execute it zero rows are displayed i have feild called distance with value null in it , when i execute this query the distance feild will be filled with some numerical value but if i specify condition distance<2 or distance <10 or ... same result gets displayed can i know the whats problem.

```
  SELECT Id,Name1,ZipCode,StreetName,StreetNumber,State1,Lat,
   Lng,Keyword, 
  ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( (12.925432/57.2958) ) 
   * COS(  (Lat/57.2958)  ) * COS( ( Lng/57.2958 ) - (77.5940171/57.2958) ) 
   + SIN( 12.925432/57.2958 ) * SIN(  Lat/57.2958  ) ) ) AS distance 
  FROM Business_Details 
  where ( 
   (StreetName like '%jayanagar%')
   and (Keyword like '%plumbing%' )
   and (distance<3)
   ) 
   ORDER BY distance;
```

Comment: Accept some answers to your previous questions, you will earn reputation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular query can be sucessfully executed by creating view in sql .
create view business as SELECT Id,Name1,ZipCode,StreetName,StreetNumber,State1,Lat,Lng,Keyword, ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( (12.925432/57.2958) ) * COS(  (Lat/57.2958)  ) * COS( ( Lng/57.2958 ) - (77.5940171/57.2958) ) + SIN( 12.925432/57.2958 ) * SIN(  Lat/57.2958  ) ) ) AS distance FROM Business_Details ORDER BY distance;
This particular view contains the results with distance feild then we can query the view business to manipulate the results for our distance value entered
select * from business where (distance<2);

Answer (score 2):

You got answers earlier...

[[How to use" HAVING "and "ORDER BY" clause in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608150/how-to-use-having-and-order-by-clause-in-sql])

You can not refer to field distance in where clause, you have to use:

```
( 6371 * ACOS( COS( (12.925432/57.2958) ) 
* COS(  (Lat/57.2958)  ) * COS( ( Lng/57.2958 ) - (77.5940171/57.2958) ) 
+ SIN( 12.925432/57.2958 ) * SIN(  Lat/57.2958  ) ) ) < 3
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,i have made changes to my query as you suggested but the result is empty i am not able to track where exactly is the problem is their any alternate way to tackle this.