# PostgreSQL - Aliases column and HAVING

Tags: postgresql, having, column-alias

```
SELECT  
CASE WHEN SUM(X.Count)*3600 is null THEN  '0'  
            ELSE  
            SUM(X.Count)*3600  
       END AS PJZ,  
       X.Mass  
FROM X  
WHERE X.Mass > 2000  
HAVING ((X.Mass / PJZ * 100) - 100) >= 10;
```

Getting: ERROR:  Column »pjz« doesn't exists.

How can I do something like this?

Comment: [Why can't I use alias in a count(*)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068682/why-cant-i-use-alias-in-a-count-column-and-reference-it-in-a-having-clause)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap it into a derived table:

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN PJZ = 0 THEN 100
          ELSE PJZ
       END as PJZ,
       mass
FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
             WHEN SUM(X.Count)*3600 is null THEN '0'  
             ELSE SUM(X.Count)*3600  
           END AS PJZ,  
           X.Mass  
    FROM X  
    WHERE X.Mass > 2000  
    GROUP BY X.mass
) t
WHERE PJZ = 0 
   OR ((X.Mass / PJZ * 100) - 100) >= 10;
```

(Note that I added the missing group by as otherwise the query would not be valid)

Comment: But now I've got the problem with division by zero. PJZ could be zero.

Comment: Then exclude the rows WHERE PJZ is zero. Or depending on your requirements return 1 (or any other non-zero value) in the CASE statement

Comment: I can't exclude the rows, because I want to see them, too. If PJZ is 0 this: ((X.Mass / PJZ * 100) - 100) should show 100 for me. So I need another IF ELSE...

Answer (score 13):

You can't use aliases in a having, and have to duplicate the statement in the having cluause. Since you only want to check for null, you could do this:

```
SELECT coalesce(SUM(X.Count)*3600, 0) AS PJZ, X.Mass
FROM X
WHERE X.Mass > 2000
HAVING ((X.Mass / coalesce(SUM(X.Count)*3600, 0) * 100) - 100) >= 10;
```

Answer (score 9):

Other option is to surround query by `WITH` statement - for example:

```
WITH x as (
  SELECT coalesce(SUM(X.Count)*3600, 0) AS PJZ, X.Mass
  FROM X
  WHERE X.Mass > 2000
)
SELECT * from X WHERE PJZ >=10
```

It is far better then code duplication in my opinion

Comment: This is beautiful. 