# Counting and finding greater then value in sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm supposed to display the name of the department in which there are at least four employees. I tried a few different methods, including this one:

```
SELECT Department, COUNT(EmployeeID) AS NumberOfEmployee
FROM Deparment d INNER JOIN Employees e
ON d.DeparmentID = e.DeparmentID
GROUP BY Deparment
HAVING NumberOfEmployee >= 4;
```

When I run the query, it is asking me to enter the parameter value for `NumberOfEmployee`.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: You can't use the alias in the having clause

Comment: @Elias : Are you sure?

Comment: @Notulysses Yes I believe this is a limitation of Access

Comment: I also thought I can't but somewhere is working. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: It's a limitation of SQL in general, not only of access. As far as I remember, the Having clause is performed before the Select clause, and as such, it does not know the aliases given in the select clause.

Comment: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068682/why-cant-i-use-alias-in-a-count-column-and-reference-it-in-a-having-clause)

Comment: @lc. : That is why I've asked, I wasn't sure about it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, that's quite correct, sorry. It's simply a "feature" of MySQL ([demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63eca/1))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT Department, COUNT(EmployeeID) AS NumberOfEmployee
FROM Deparment d INNER JOIN Employees e
ON d.DeparmentID = e.DeparmentID
GROUP BY Deparment
HAVING COUNT(EmployeeID) >= 4;
```

Your original HAVING clause was invalid (you cannot use an alias in it).

Comment: @Mplus: On StackExchange sites, like StackOverflow (aka. SO), it's considered proper etiquette to mark the correct answer as the 'accepted answer'. Both to show all other SO readers that your question has been answered as well as to give the individual who spent time to answer your question credit for taking the time to do so. Welcome to StackOverflow!