# Access, using VBA to auto match records between 2 recordsets

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, recordset, database-reconciliation

I have a database in Access, and another table in excel.

I'm trying to build a reconciliation macro within access, that will hopefully mark all the records in Access that have a matching entry in excel. The excel will also be marked off, so I will know which records were not matched to look at manually.

What I've done so far is to convert the excel table into an array, then move that into a recordset "ldict" to reduce the worksheet interaction and hopefully will speed up the macro.

I did the same with the table in Access, and moved it into a recordset "RS".

At this point, I've been using nested loops. It'll move through each record in ldict, then loop through each record in RS to find a match.

When it finds a match, I have a boolean field "CMN_REV" in RS that will be set to TRUE to indicate it was matched.

In ldict, it will copy the matched PK_ID from RS, as a record of what was matched.

```vb
Dim xl As Excel.Application, wb As Excel.Workbook, lfilepath As String, ldict As ADODB.Recordset, lrow As Long, i As Long, _
legacy As Excel.Worksheet, legacy2 As Excel.Worksheet, str As String, arr() As Variant

'setup ldict
Set ldict = New ADODB.Recordset
With ldict.Fields
    .Append ......
End With
ldict.Open

'set legacy file
lfilepath = Dir(Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\test.csv")
Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")
With xl
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .Visible = True
    Set wb = .Workbooks.Open(Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\" & lfilepath)
    Set legacy = wb.Worksheets(1)


    'move excel to array to recordset.
    With legacy

        lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        arr = .Range("A1:AM" & lrow)

        For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 1)
                With ldict
                    .AddNew
                    .......
                    .Update
                End With
        Next i
        Erase arr()

        Set legacy2 = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.count))
        legacy2.Name = "Results"
        wb.SaveAs FileName:=Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "Output", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, _
            ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges

    End With
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With


'setup RS
Dim rs As Recordset, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Unpaid query")
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")

qdf.sql = "Update AR_Consolidated set CMN_REV = '0'"
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError

ldict.MoveFirst
rs.MoveFirst

'compare loop
While Not ldict.EOF

    'end of rs wend sets absolute to -1. check to reset to first position
    If rs.EOF = True Then
        rs.MoveFirst
    End If

    While Not rs.EOF

        'convert rs expiry to dates
        Select Case Left(rs("MON_YR"), 3)
            Case Is = "JAN"
                i = 1
            Case Is = "FEB"
                i = 2
            Case Is = "MAR"
                i = 3
            Case Is = "APR"
                i = 4
            Case Is = "MAY"
                i = 5
            Case Is = "JUN"
                i = 6
            Case Is = "JUL"
                i = 7
            Case Is = "AUG"
                i = 8
            Case Is = "SEP"
                i = 9
            Case Is = "OCT"
                i = 10
            Case Is = "NOV"
                i = 11
            Case Is = "DEC"
                i = 12
        End Select

        'check conditions
        If rs("CMN_REV") = False _
        And (Trim(ldict("area")) = Trim(rs("area")) Or Trim(ldict("area")) = Trim(rs("MIC"))) _
        And Trim(ldict("Firm")) = Trim(rs("Firm")) _
        And ldict("Product") = rs("Product_Code") _
        And ldict("Expiry") = DateSerial(Right(rs("MON_YR"), 2), i, "01") _
        And Round(ldict("Price"), 3) = Round(Val(rs("Price")), 3) _
        And ldict("Date") = rs("Date") _
        And ldict("Quantity") = rs("Quantity") And ldict("Amount") = rs("Amount") _
        And ldict("BuySell") = rs("BUY/SELL") _
        And ldict("Currency") = rs("CurrCode") _
        And ldict("Amount") = rs("Amount") _
        Then

        'perform actions if matched

            'set matched indicator in rs
            rs.Edit
                rs![CMN_REV] = True
            rs.Update

            ldict("PK_ID").Value = rs("PK_ID").Value
            ldict.Update


            GoTo a
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Wend
a:
    ldict.MoveNext
Wend

'copy from ldict into excel

If ldict.BOF = False And ldict.EOF = False Then
    ldict.MoveFirst
End If
legacy2.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset ldict
wb.Save
```

While the code works perfectly, it is unfortunately too slow. I have avg 100k records for each recordset, and it seems to take hours if not days.

As it moves on to each record in ldict, it will loop through the beginning of RS again.

I've consider possibly removing matched records in RS when it finds one, so it does not have to look at the same record again on the next loop, but i believe this will also remove it from my Table in Access.

I've read some suggestions that using joined SQL queries would be faster, but i'm not sure how to approach this to achieve the same results.

Anyone have any better suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: All of the tests in your large If clause will get run even if the first one fails, so maybe consider splitting that up into nested If statements with the most "discriminating" ones running first.

Comment: Thanks Tim. That makes sense. I even nested my Select statement. Seems to have sped it up considerably, but looks like it would still take a few hours to complete..

Comment: Yes Jeff's suggestion is likely to be a better way to go.  Either link your excel sheet or import the Excel records to a table in access (adding in the worksheet row number so you can track back after the comparison is run)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility for doing this with SQL instead of VBA would be creating a [linked table in Access](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/import-or-link-to-data-in-an-excel-workbook-a1952878-7c58-47b1-893d-e084913cc958) from your Excel workbook. Then you can run a query against the two datasets.

I'm not sure about directly updating your Excel file, but you should at least be able to use a select query to see which rows in Excel aren't matched. Untested, but something like this is the general idea:

```
select * 
from [YourExcelTable] e
where not exists (
  select 1
  from [YourAccessTable] a
  where (Trim(e.area) = Trim(a.area) Or Trim(e.area) = Trim(a.MIC))
        And Trim(e.Firm) = Trim(a.Firm)
        And e.Product = a.Product_Code
        And e.Expiry = DateSerial(Right(a.MON_YR, 2), i, "01")
        And Round(e.Price, 3) = Round(Val(a.Price), 3)
        And e.Date = a.Date
        And e.Quantity = a.Quantity 
        And e.Amount = a.Amount
        And e.BuySell = a.[BUY/SELL]
        And e.Currency = a.CurrCode
        And e.Amount = a.Amount
)
```

EDIT: Per the question below, if you wanted to find the matches, and you wanted to be able to show fields from both tables, you could use a JOIN instead of EXISTS. You could probably reduce the number of fields in the join, but because I'm not familiar with your data I'm going to assume here that all fields are necessary to make a proper match.

```
select e.*, a.ID
from [YourExcelTable] e
inner join [YourAccessTable] a
    On (Trim(e.area) = Trim(a.area) Or Trim(e.area) = Trim(a.MIC))
        And Trim(e.Firm) = Trim(a.Firm)
        And e.Product = a.Product_Code
        And e.Expiry = DateSerial(Right(a.MON_YR, 2), i, "01")
        And Round(e.Price, 3) = Round(Val(a.Price), 3)
        And e.Date = a.Date
        And e.Quantity = a.Quantity 
        And e.Amount = a.Amount
        And e.BuySell = a.[BUY/SELL]
        And e.Currency = a.CurrCode
        And e.Amount = a.Amount
```

Comment: No link needed, you can [MS ACCESS SQL query Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320695/ms-access-sql-query-excel-sheet).

Comment: Thanks for the link and suggestion. Will try this out and experiment.

Comment: Using this method, but with a WHERE EXIST, to show matched entries from 'e', is it possible to also select the a.ID that corresponds to the matched record in 'e'? 

I tried Selecting it in the first Where clause, but it just does a Cartesian product. 

I think I need a JOIN, my understanding of JOINS is that it needs a common field. I'm not sure how to apply it to this, since I would have multiple common fields and 1 sub-query... is it possible?

Ty

Comment: You're correct that you need a join, and every field in your current query would go into the join. I can update my answer to show you, hold please :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help!