# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "order_count" does not exist when .having('order_count > 5')

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Context: I am using Active Admin and would like to define a scope to show me any Users with more than 5 orders in the next week. This is a Postgres DB in a Rails app.

```
User.where(vetting_status: ["Enabled"]).joins(:orders).where('orders.date >= ? AND orders.date <= ?', Date.today, Date.today + 6.days).select('users.first_name, COUNT(orders.id) AS order_count').group('users.first_name').having('order_count > 5').order('order_count desc')
```

However, this gives me the following error when I try to run it: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "order_count" does not exist`

The issue is with the `.having('order_count > 5')` as I can run the query if I remove that part. However, that's the crucial part and I'm not sure what I'm getting wrong. I've tried `.having('gardener.order_count > 5')` and `.having('orders.order_count > 5')` but neither of those worked either. Thanks in advance for help. P.S. I have searched a fair few answers and couldn't find a solution.

Comment: `orders.order_count` try use this.

Comment: I had already tried that - same error message. More precisely: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column orders.order_count does not exist`

Comment: Hey, i got the error, check the answer below. Feel free to accept answer if it helped you. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The HAVING clause is evaluated before the SELECT - so the server doesn't yet know about that alias.

Instead of `COUNT(orders.id) AS order_count` you should do `count(orders) as order_count` [You can look around here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count)
I have tried so far below and its working, hopefully it will help you.

```
User.where(vetting_status: ["Enabled"]).joins(:orders).where('orders.date >= ? AND orders.date <= ?', Date.today, Date.today + 6.days).group('users.first_name').having('count(orders) > 5').order('count(orders) desc').select('users.first_name')
```

Alternatively you should do as with your above query: -

```
count(orders) as order_count
```

This also means the it will get total orders of user as order count.
like this: -

```
User.where(vetting_status: ["Enabled"]).joins(:orders).where('orders.date >= ? AND orders.date <= ?', Date.today, Date.today + 6.days).select('users.first_name, count(orders) as order_count').group('users.first_name').having('count(orders) > 5').order('order_count desc')
```

Hence both answers are working without any error. :D

Comment: Still no joy. I get `User.where(vetting_status: ["Enabled"]).joins(:orders).where('orders.date >= ? AND orders.date <= ?', Date.today, Date.today + 6.days).select('users.first_name, count(orders) as order_count').group('users.first_name').having('order_count > 5').order('order_count desc')
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "order_count" does not exist
`

Comment: @KhaledMcGonnell Hmm sorry, i got the same error at my console, and  i figured out that its issue with having clause  `having('count(orders) > 5')` and its working fine, and i think having clause doesn't accept the alias coumn name.

Comment: @KhaledMcGonnell 
`User.where(vetting_status: ["Enabled"]).joins(:orders).where('orders.date >= ? AND orders.date <= ?', Date.today, Date.today + 6.days).select('users.first_name, count(orders) as order_count').group('users.first_name').having('count(orders) > 5').order('order_count desc')`

it will work fine. try this and let me know the same.

Comment: @KhaledMcGonnell Well today i came to know this also, that alias coulmn name can't be used with having clause check out this: -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068682/why-cant-i-use-alias-in-a-count-column-and-reference-it-in-a-having-clause/2068705

Comment: That works and that's very useful to know the alias doesn't work. Thank you!